How to use Kotlin Flows in flutter plugin
What is the proper way to use kotlin flows in a flutter plugin?
All the code i've seen references the view lifecycle, lifecycle scope, and view models, but none of those are available in a flutter plugin from what I can tell. Here's an example of some code to collect flow data.
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.getWeatherForecast().collect {
                // Use the weather forecast data
        }
}

Does any have know of how to handle this or know of any articles/example that could help?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
